# Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have several queries which look like the following. Is there any way to improve the performance or to change that below query in such a way which give better performance? We have already implemented indexes.

```
SELECT COLUMN
FROM ABC
LEFT JOIN XYZ ON XYZ.ID=ABC.ID
AND ABC.COlumn_3='Y'
AND ABC.Column_4='Y'
AND XYZ.ID_2 =
  (SELECT TOP 1 ID_2
   FROM XYZ
   WHERE XYZ.ID = ABC.ID
   ORDER BY ID_2 DESC)
```

Comment: Is this mySQL or SQL server?

Comment: Are you really only selecting a single column? That seems unlikely with the rest of the query given. So: How many columns do you actually want to select from ABC, how many from XYZ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN
FROM ABC
LEFT JOIN XYZ ON XYZ.ID=ABC.ID
    AND ABC.COlumn_3='Y'
    AND ABC.Column_4='Y'
ORDER BY XYZ.ID_2 DESC
```

Just took a look at your query, the last `AND XYZ.ID_2` filtering is a bit redundant.

Also, IF possible, try using INNER JOIN, it's faster

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is not to use sub queries. They will be executed for each row. If you have a static value that you want to get, store in a variable:

```
@value = (Select TOP 1 ID_2 From XYZ);
SELECT Column FROM ABC LEFT JOIN XYZ ON XYZ.ID=ABC.ID AND ABC.COlumn_3='Y' AND ABC.Column_4='Y' AND XYZ.ID_2 = @value
```

As you use a dynamic value, do it with a join:

```
SELECT Column 
FROM ABC 
LEFT JOIN XYZ ON XYZ.ID=ABC.ID AND ABC.COlumn_3='Y' AND ABC.Column_4='Y'
LEFT JOIN (Select TOP 1 ID_2 From XYZ Where XYZ.ID = ABC.ID Order By ID_2 DESC) XYZ2 ON XYZ.ID = XYZ2.ID_2
```

Not sure if the queries are 100% correct, but hope you get my point.